# Mots avec et sans accent avec un sens différent

Tags: diacritiques

Bonjour,

Existe-t-il une liste exhaustive des mots (je cherche surtout des noms communs et noms propres) dont le sens est différent selon qu'il est écrit avec ou sans accents (ou autres diacritiques).

Par exemple :

- maïs (plante) vs mais (conjonction)
- intimé (justiciable) vs intime (lié étroitement)

J'ai besoin de cela pour estimer les risques de collisions quand j'analyse des textes anciens écrits tout en majuscule ou quand j'analyse des textes modernes dont les majuscules ont été enlevées.

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: *dont les accents ont été enlevés* ?

Answer (score 4):

La première liste qui me vient à l'esprit est tous les verbes du premier groupe entre le participe passé (avec accent aigu : *chanté*, *mangé* ...) et la deuxième personne de l'impératif présent (sans accent : *chante*, *mange* ...)

D'autre part cet exemple me semble intéressant (nuance entre le participe passé et l'adjectif) :

- Un ancien *interne/interné* des hôpitaux. (le docteur ou le malade)

On peut distinguer aussi :

- ou et où
- la et là
- pêcheur et pécheur
- tache et tâche

En utilisant [cette liste](http://www.pallier.org/ressources/dicofr/dicofr.html), qui contient également les formes conjuguées des verbes, et moyennant un petit script j'obtiens une liste impressionnante de 12820 mots qui se déclinent en 2,3 ou 4 expressions avec et sans accents.

Je ne pense pas qu'il soit possible de la poster ici.

De cette liste, j'ai supprimé les formes verbales (ex. chante/chanté) ainsi que les pluriels. Voici le début de cette liste réduite, uniquement pour les mots en « a », le chiffre indique le nombre de déclinaisons) :

```
(2)a : a, à
(2)abime : abîme, abîmé
(2)absente : absente, absenté
(2)accouche : accouche, accouché
(2)acre : acre, âcre
(2)adresse : adresse, adressé
(2)adultere : adultéré, adultère
(2)affaire : affaire, affairé
(2)afferent : afférent, affèrent
(2)agave : agave, agavé
(2)age : âge, âgé
(2)agence : agence, agencé
(2)agences : agences, agencés
(2)agglomerat : agglomérat, agglomérât
(2)agrafe : agrafe, agrafé
(2)ai : ai, aï
(2)aide : aide, aidé
(2)aigrette : aigrette, aigretté
(2)aile : aile, ailé
(2)aimante : aimante, aimanté
(2)aine : aine, aîné
(2)ais : ais, aïs
(2)aise : aise, aisé
(2)alambique : alambique, alambiqué
(2)alarme : alarme, alarmé
(2)albumine : albumine, albuminé
(2)alerte : alerte, alerté
(2)alese : alésé, alèse
(2)alumine : alumine, aluminé
(2)alveole : alvéole, alvéolé
(2)amalgame : amalgame, amalgamé
(2)amarre : amarre, amarré
(2)amble : amble, amblé
(2)ambre : ambre, ambré
(2)amende : amende, amendé
(2)amnistie : amnistie, amnistié
(2)amorce : amorce, amorcé
(2)ampoule : ampoule, ampoulé
(2)amure : amure, amuré
(2)analyse : analyse, analysé
(2)ancre : ancre, ancré
(2)anemie : anémie, anémié
(2)anesthesie : anesthésie, anesthésié
(2)anglaise : anglaise, anglaisé
(2)angoisse : angoisse, angoissé
(2)annexe : annexe, annexé
(2)annonce : annonce, annoncé
(2)apostasie : apostasie, apostasié
(2)apostat : apostat, apostât
(2)apostrophe : apostrophe, apostrophé
(2)applique : applique, appliqué
(2)approche : approche, approché
(2)apres : après, âpres
(2)arbitre : arbitre, arbitré
(2)arme : arme, armé
(2)arpege : arpégé, arpège
(2)arriere : arriéré, arrière
(2)arsouille : arsouille, arsouillé
(2)asperge : asperge, aspergé
(2)asphalte : asphalte, asphalté
(2)asphyxie : asphyxie, asphyxié
(2)assassinat : assassinat, assassinât
(2)assiege : assiégé, assiège
(2)assignat : assignat, assignât
(2)atrophie : atrophie, atrophié
(2)attentat : attentat, attentât
(2)augure : augure, auguré
(2)aureole : auréole, auréolé
(2)autopsie : autopsie, autopsié
(2)avance : avance, avancé
(2)avantage : avantage, avantagé
(2)avarie : avarie, avarié
(2)aventure : aventure, aventuré
(2)aveugle : aveugle, aveuglé
(2)aveuglement : aveuglement, aveuglément
(2)avoue : avoue, avoué
(2)axe : axe, axé
(2)azote : azote, azoté
```

Comment: Pour moi, cette liste contient trop de paires qui se rapportent au même sens: atrophie, atrophié parle toujours d'atrophie. Antoine a précisé qu'il était plutôt intéressé par des paires telles que: après, âpres. :-)

Comment: @Frank: C'est très sympa de mettre un vote négatif ! J'ai essayé de ne garder que des noms communs, éventuellement opposés à des participes passé, il en reste quelques uns, il suffit de faire le tri. Je ne suis pas une machine.  Tu n'as qu'à fournir toi-même une liste

Comment: J'ai mis un vote négatif? Si c'est le cas, je l'enlève, ce n'était pas l'intention. Ceci dit, je trouve la liste de jlliagre ci-dessous plus ciblée.

Answer (score 3):

- forêt / foret
- mât / mat
- aïe / aie
- même / mème
- porte / porté *(noms communs)*

Le fameux :

> HOPITAL DE PARIS : UN INTERNE TUE

Interne ou interné ? Tue ou tué ?

Answer (score 3):

La liste des homographes par neutralisation des accents est énorme mais il y a aussi les homographes non homophones comme dans *les poules du couvent couvent*.

[Lexique3](http://lexique.org/) est une ressource lexicale gratuite qui contient 135000 formes de 55000 mots. Un informaticien de votre entourage pourrait facilement compiler une liste d'homographes par neutralisations des accents (ou d'homographes qui dépendent de mots différents comme *couvent*).

Answer (score 3):

En supprimant les verbes conjugués, j'en extrais un peu moins de mille de la base [Lexique](http://lexique.org/), dont voici une petite sélection :

```
acre - âcre
aine - aîné
ampoule - ampoulé
aveuglement - aveuglément
bandes - bandés
baraque - baraqué
basanes - basanés
blase - blasé
blindes - blindés
bombes - bombés
bonde - bondé
bouche - bouché
brises - brisés
bronzes - bronzés
caille - caillé
carre - carré
cendres - cendrés
charme - charmé
chasse - châsse
chique - chiqué
cintre - cintré
colon - côlon
combine - combiné
combles - comblés
comite - comité
comte - comté
congres - congrès
corses - corsés
cote - côté
cure - curé
de - dé
demeure - demeuré
demis - démis
des - dés
du - dû
enseignes - enseignés
faite - faîte
figures - figurés
foret - forêt
fosse - fossé
fripe - fripé
frises - frisés
gaze - gazé
gondoles - gondolés
gorge - gorgé
grade - gradé
greffe - greffé
grises - grisés
haches - hachés
haie - haïe
hale - hâlé
homologue - homologué
iles - îles
indigne - indigné
infectes - infectés
informe - informé
interne - interné
isolement - isolément
jeune - jeûne
joue - joué
juge - jugé
la - là
laisse - laissé
lames - lamés
lave - lavé
le - lé
les - lés
lettre - lettré
lie - lié
loges - logés
loupe - loupé
lunes - lunés
lustres - lustrés
male - mâle
marche - marché
marine - mariné
mat - mât
matin - mâtin
matines - mâtines
mats - mâts
mature - mâture
membre - membré
miches - michés
moi - moï
moise - Moïse
mole - môle
moule - moulé
mur - mûr
mutine - mutiné
ne - né
noue - noué
ou - où
outres - outrés
pagaie - pagaïe
pale - pâle
palot - pâlot
panache - panaché
pape - papé
passe - passé
paume - paumé
phrase - phrasé
poire - poiré
pole - pôle
polices - policés
ponte - ponté
praline - praliné
quadruples - quadruplés
quinte - quinté
rais - raïs
rate - raté
reformation - réformation
rot - rôt
roues - roués
sable - sablé
sacrement - sacrément
sale - salé
signe - signé
soude - soudé
souffle - soufflé
soule - soûle
sur - sûr
tache - tâche
tape - tapé
tare - taré
tasses - tassés
te - té
tentes - tentés
tenu - ténu
tiare - tiaré
tierce - tiercé
timbres - timbrés
tires - tirés
tombes - tombés
toque - toqué
trace - tracé
triples - triplés
trompe - trompé
type - typé
verges - vergés
```

Comment: Vous avez une référence pour cette base "Lexique"?

Comment: @Frank C'est celle déjà évoquée par GAM PUB.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 2):

Une telle liste serait vraiment très longue.

La plupart des verbes en français sont dits "du premier groupe", on les reconnait parce qu'à l'infinitif ils se terminent en "-er" (comme "chanter", "danser" et "manger"). Pour tous ces verbes, la forme participe passé est en "-é" ("chanté", "dansé", "mangé") et la forme à la troisième personne du singulier au présent est en "-e" ("il chante", "il danse", "il mange").

Rien que qu'en comptant ces verbes, la liste est immense, mais il y a encore d'autres formes conjuguées qui sont les mêmes à une diacritique près.

Comment: I wouldn't count the examples based on verbs, as the meaning is different, but it still has to do with singing, walking... :-)

Comment: En effet, ma question porte plutôt sur des noms et adjectifs que sur toutes les formes de verbes.

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux Dans ce cas, ce n'est pas "une liste exhaustive" que tu cherches. De plus les participes passés peuvent être utilisés comme adjectifs.